# Geometric Series $\sum_{k=0}^{\log_{2}n}\frac{n}{2^k}$

Tags: summation, logarithms, geometric-series

I am trying to figure out how to solve this summation:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\log_{2}n}\frac{n}{2^k}$$.

(k and n are positive real integers)

I recognize that this is a geometric series if we do this:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\log_{2}n}n\cdot 2^{-k}$$

Im confused on where to solve it because of the $\log_{2}n$.

Comment: The $n$ in the sum is irrelevant, it just factors out of the sum.  What's left is an ordinary Geometric series (trusting that $n$ is a power of $2$ or that you intended to write $\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor$).

Comment: I am confused weather its to be treated as integral or a sum. I mean weather k takes integral value or reals

Comment: Well,  we can't guess the intent of whomever set the problem.  It's written as a sum...I'd take it at its word.  Just use the floor.

Comment: @TamaghnaChaudhuri k takes positive integers, sorry for not clarifying

Comment: Please clarify the convention you are using for the upper limit, $\log_2n$. Do you stop at the floor, the ceiling, or the *closest* integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S=n\sum_{k=0}^{-1+\log_2 n} 2^{-k} = \frac{2^{-(\log_2 n)}-1}{1/2-1} = n \frac{1/n-1}{-1/2}=2(n-1).$$ and $$S=n\sum_{k=0}^{\log_2 n} 2^{-k} = n \frac{2^{-(\log_2 n)-1}-1}{1/2-1} = n \frac{1/(2n)-1}{-1/2}=2n-1.$$
So $\log_2 n$ not being an integer, we may assert that $$2n-2 <S_n <2n-1.$$
I guess nothing better than this could be done.

Comment: Why do you use asymptotic equivalence ?

Comment: Something should be said about the upper bound not being an integer...

Comment: Er, sorry to cause all this trouble, but aren't the two sums identical ?

Comment: Am I blind ? The sums are character per character identical, even in the LaTeX code.

Comment: Mh, there is still no remark about $\log_2n$ not being an integer, and the last inequalities can be violated.

Comment: @Yves Daoust, Thanks for your comments I have improved  my answer.

Comment: If the upper bound is understood to be the floor of the expression, I am afraid that your results are wrong for all $n$ (even powers of $2$).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**    According to rules when using the sigma-symbol $\sum$ we have for real  $a\geq 0$:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^a f(k)&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor a\rfloor} f(k)\\
&=f(0)+f(1)+\cdots+f\left(\lfloor a\rfloor\right)
\end{align*}
where *[$\lfloor  a\rfloor$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)* means the greatest integer less or equal to $a$. See for instance   chapter 2: *Sums* , section 2.1 *Notation* in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*
by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{\log_{2}n}n\cdot 2^{-k}}&=n\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \log_{2}n \rfloor}2^{-k}\\
> &=n\cdot\frac{1-2^{-\left(\lfloor\log_{2}n\rfloor +1\right)}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=n\left(2-2^{-\lfloor\log_{2}n\rfloor}\right)}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

In the special case $n=2^N$we have  $$\lfloor \log_{2}n \rfloor=\lfloor \log_{2}2^N \rfloor=\lfloor N\rfloor=N$$   and obtain from (1):
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\log_{2}2^N}2^N\cdot 2^{-k}=2^N\sum_{k=0}^{N} 2^{-k}=2^N\left(2-2^{-N}\right)=2^{N+1}-1
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

For any natural $m$,

$$\sum_{k=0}^m\frac n{2^k}=2n\left(1-\frac1{2^{m+1}}\right).$$

Now up to you to figure out what $m$ is (read the comments by lulu and Barry Cipra).